# error MSB1009: Project file does not exist on running fromCruiseControl

Tags: svn, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

Following is my ccnet.config file, When running this file from ccnet webpage, it is giving me error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. ANy idea where I am doing wrong

```
    <project>
      <name>ITR Test</name>
      <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet/</webURL>

      <triggers>
        <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="30" initialSeconds="30"/>
      </triggers>

      <modificationDelaySeconds>2</modificationDelaySeconds>

      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <executable>c:\program files\subversion\bin\svn.exe</executable>
        <trunkUrl>svn://ka/le/TestReports</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>
          C:\source\TestReports\ITRTests\ITRTests\ITRTests
        </workingDirectory>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <!-- Use MsBuild to build the .Net solution-->
        <msbuild>
          <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
          <workingDirectory>
            C:\source\TestReports\ITRTests\ITRTests\
          </workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>ITRTests.sln</projectFile>
          <targets>RunAutomationTests</targets>
          <timeout>15</timeout>
        </msbuild>

        <!-- Use NUnit for unit testing-->
        <nunit path="C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit-console.exe">
          <assemblies>
            <!--Path to Visual Studio project executable-->
            <assembly>
              C:\source\TestReports\ITRTests\ITRTests\ITRTests\bin\Debug\ITRTests.dll
            </assembly>
          </assemblies>
        </nunit>

        <!-- Email notification to users -->
        <email from="xxx@example.com" mailhost="hostname" mailport="25" includeDetails="TRUE"
             mailhostUsername="username" mailhostPassword="password" useSSL="FALSE" >
          <users>
            <!-- <user name="LeadDeveloper" group="buildmaster" address="mailto:aaa@aaa.com /> -->
            <!-- <user name="Developer1" group="developers" address="mailto:bbb@bbb.com /> -->
          </users>
          <groups>
            <!-- <group name="buildmaster" notification="always" /> -->
            <!-- <group name="developers" notification="change" /> -->
          </groups>
        </email>

      </tasks>

      <publishers>
        <merge>
          <files>
            <file>C:\source\TestReports\ITRTests\ITRTests\ITRTests\bin\Debug\TestResult.xml</file>
          </files>
        </merge>
        <xmllogger/>
      </publishers>

    </project>
  </cruisecontrol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sourcecontrol block appears to be placing the code in "C:\source\TestReports\ITRTests\ITRTests\ITRTests" (note the three levels of 'ITRTests') but the msbuild task has a working directory of "C:\source\TestReports\ITRTests\ITRTests\" (only two levels of 'ITRTests')